# How to prove strict complementary slackness by means of Farkas' lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, linear-programming

This question relates to pages 89 and 96 the following text (pages 102 and 109 of the pdf):

https://promathmedia.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/alexander_schrijver_theory_of_linear_and_integerbookfi-org.pdf

**The author gives the following variant of Farkas' lemma:**

Let $A$ be a matrix and $b$ be a vector. Then the system of linear inequalities $Ax \le b$ has a solution $x$, if and only if $yb \ge 0$ for each row vector $y \ge 0$ with $yA = 0$.

**He then proves that:**

for a bounded and feasible linear program

$$\max \{ cx \mid Ax \le b \} = \min \{ yb \mid y \ge 0, yA = c \} $$

if the maximum problem has no optimum $x_0$ with $a_ix_0 \lt b_i$ then the minimum problem must have an optimum $y_0$ with a positive $\mathit{i}$th component.

**The proof starts as follows:**

It is assumed that there is no optimum solution $x_0$ for the maximum problem with $a_ix_0 \lt b_i$.
Then, if $\delta$ is the optimum value of the maximum and minimum problems, $Ax \le b, cx \ge \delta$ implies $a_ix \ge \beta_i$. So, by Corollary 7.1e (Farkas' lemma as given above), $yA - \lambda c = -a_i$ and $yb - \lambda \delta \le -\beta_i$ for some $y, \lambda \ge 0$.

**My question is:**

How does the last sentence ("So") follow from what preceeds it?

Specifically, how can "$Ax \le b, cx \ge \delta$ implies $a_ix \ge \beta_i$" be cast in a form such that application of Farkas' lemma yields $yA - \lambda c = -a_i$ and $yb - \lambda \delta \le -\beta_i$ for some $y, \lambda \ge 0$?

Neither the positive form ("$Ax \le b, -cx \le -\delta, -a_ix \le -\beta_i$ has a solution") nor the negative form ("$Ax \le b, -cx \le -\delta, a_ix \le \beta'_i$, with $\beta'_i \lt \beta_i$, has no solution") yields exactly the desired inequalities when Farkas' lemma is applied. For example, signs or inequality directions differ from those sought.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\beta_i = b_i$, right? And the 'implies' part makes it seem like you need to use the second part of Farkas lemma.

Comment: Yes. $\beta_i = b_i$. I tried using the second part of Farkas' lemma but couldn't get anywhere with it.

Comment: The linked book, on top of page 96 (109 of the pdf), refers to Corollary 7.1h, not 7.1e. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. My hard copy, which appears to be an older edition, says 7.1e. I hadn't notice the discrepancy.

In fact, by using the second part of the Farkas' Lemma variant of Corollary 7.1d ("There exists a vector $x \ge 0$ with $Ax = b$,  if and only if $yb \ge 0$ for each row vector $y$ with $yA \ge 0$"), I have managed to get Schrijver's result, but with two equations rather than one equation and an inequality.

Comment: But with 7.1e it is clear now, right? If you would like me to look at your solution via 7.1d, please share your attempt.

Comment: I have had a look at Corollary 7.1h, and with it, the desired result can be obtained immediately.